# How to create a workbook array dynamically in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add workbook objects to an array of workbooks
The array is of type public created in a separate module

```
Option Explicit
Public w() As Workbook
Public i As Integer
```

then i have the below procedure in a sub stored in a worksheet

```
Sub test_addwbobjects()
ReDim Preserve w(2)
Application.Workbooks("Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx").Activate
Set w(i) = ActiveWorkbook
'Set w(i) = Application.Workbooks("Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx")
i = i + 1
'ActiveSheet.Range("b2") = w(0).Sheets("CF analysis").Range("b2")
'ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = w(i).Sheets("CF analysis").Range("b2")
'ActiveSheet.Range("b2") = w(1).Sheets("CF analysis").Range("b5")
End Sub
```

Context:
The workbook "Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx" contains a financial model of a company. I want to be able to compare financial information of multiple companies, so for that purpose I want to create a workbook object every time I paste a company's financials into the "Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx" workbook

I am currently getting the subscript out of range error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Is **Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx** already open?

Comment: This seems counter-productive. Your commented line seems to rely upon a very specific worksheet name. Might be better to use a variant array of workbook names and encapsulate the referenced workbook in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). It is hard to offer more without a wider overview of what you are trying to accomplish. (hint - you would have to [ReDim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) the **w** array before assigning values or objects to it)

Comment: Yes, Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx is open.

Comment: thanks, your hint has worked. So we have know the array size before assigning anything to it?

Comment: Here is a link on loop through workbooks, [Loop through a Folder of Workbooks](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Loop%20Through%20Folder) and a short clip on that as well..[Loop through a folder of workbooks,copy and paste data](https://youtu.be/6XsvI9i2z7s)

Comment: Try using [ReDim Preserve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) before adding items to the array

Comment: @xmojmr Redim Preserve has improved things but the problem that i have currently is that all the array objects are referring to the most recently entered values in "Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx". It means that the data present in the file "quick analysis..." the moment the line Set w(i) = Application.Workbooks("Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx") was executed is not getting copied in the object w(i).

Comment: When we assign activesheet to a worksheet object, the object continues to refer to the old data even if the activesheet changes, so i tried with activeworkbook but i have the same problem

Comment: @Navkanth can you add some more code to your question? Longer `test_addwbobjects` or where is it called from?

Comment: @xmojmr i have updated the code for test_addwbobjects. This sub is present in a workbook called "company comparison" and I am calling it from one of its worksheets to get data from "quick analysis..." present at that point in time. I have two workbooks open "Quick analysis..." and "company comparison". (commented lines are for testing and verification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
Public w As Collection

Sub Test_addWBObject()

    Set w = New Collection

    w.Add Item:=Workbooks("Quick analysis - Moneycontrol.xlsx"), _
          Key:="MyUniqueKeyForThisWorkbook"

    'Can use collection as this:
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = w(1).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")

    'or this
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = w("MyUniqueKeyForThisWorkbook").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")

    'or this
    Dim wrkBk As Variant
    For Each wrkBk In w
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = wrkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    Next wrkBk

    'or this
    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To w.Count
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = w(x).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")
    Next x

End Sub
```